# Jquery Ajax problem inside a function

Tags: jquery, ajax

this code always return "0":

```
function myFunc() {

var str = "0";

JQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "test.aspx/testMethod",
      data: "{}",
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: function(msg) {

       alert(str); //here shows my value from my method
       str = msg.d;

      }

});

alert(str); //here shows "0";

return str;
```

But the return value of my js function is always "0".
I think the JavaScript returns str before the ajax is completed. What I could do?

}

Comment: Have you set breakpoints on the server side to see if your page method is being called? Checked with Firebug / IE developer tools / whatever to see what the response from the server was, if the call is failing?

Comment: yes, the value returns normally. my first alert shows the value from db

Comment: I think ajax function has a delay because this method search in my big database, so I think my js function continues running itself while ajax running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. Alert is being called before you hear back from the server. If you don't want the .ajax call to return immediately, you can set async to false. Does this work?

```
function myFunc() {

var str = "0";

JQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      async: false,
      url: "test.aspx/testMethod",
      data: "{}",
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: function(msg) {

       alert(str); //here shows my value from my method
       str = msg.d;

      }

});

alert(str); //here shows "0";

return str;
}
```

I should point out that the way you are doing this probably isn't the most appropriate. You are trying to create a function which works syncronously because that is simple and it's what you are used to. However, it defeats the whole purpose of asynchronous requests, and doesn't fit the paradigms of Javascript well. Here's what the jQuery documentation has to say about this:

> Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active.

It would be better to have a callback function which uses the value that you get back from your request.